# Unable to add grid title to gridview using DevExpress vb.net

Tags: vb.net, gridview, devexpress-windows-ui

I've tried the following code found on the DevExpress site but I get a NullReferenceException
at the `view.Bands.Clear()`

```
Dim view As BandedGridView = TryCast(gridControl1.MainView, BandedGridView)
view.Bands.Clear()

'Create the bands layout.  
 Dim bandProdInf As GridBand = view.Bands.Add()
 bandProdInf.Caption = "Notification Details - Drilling"
```

This would be the look of the gridview that I would like:
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Attachment/GetAttachmentFile/e5cb046f-fb25-46a4-9ae8-25ba612daa01

"Notification Details - Drilling" would appear as the title of the gridview.

Comment: if `TryCast` cannot perform the cast, it returns `Nothing`. Using the result without testing will cause an NRE when it cant perform the cast.  From MSDN: *...TryCast returns Nothing (Visual Basic), so that instead of having to handle a possible exception, you need only test the returned result against Nothing.*

Comment: I guess this explains why I'm getting a NullReferenceException.  Thanks for that.  However, I'm still unable to add a grid title to my gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The support team from devexpress provided the following right answer:

The GridView offers a built-in mechanism for showing a title via the ViewCaption property. Additionally you will want to set the GridView's OptionsView.ShowViewCaption property to True.

So you would do the following:

```
gridview1.ViewCaption = "Grid view title"
gridview1.OptionsView.ShowViewCaption = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Captions must be enabled, they're disabled by default.
Add:

```
  view.OptionsView.ShowViewCaption = true;
```